# Robust multivariate Wald test for significance in proportional odds model

Tags: inference, ordered-logit, robust-standard-error

I am using the `rms` package (Harrell) to estimate a proportional odds model to determine the association between an ordinal outcome (frequency of pain) and the exposure of interest (3 level factor, acculturation, measured jointly by non-English household language and self-reported ethnicity).

According to the assumptions of the proportional odds model, the intercepts that are estimated in the pseudolikelihood, allow the model to estimate an unknown "distance" between the logit functions as you compare various cumulative logit models with a common odds ratio.  These are estimated directly, but function as nuissance parameters (except for verifying the proportional odds assumption, which I believe can be relaxed in robust variance estimation).

Do we need to estimate a null model in multivariate inference? The robust multivariate Wald test statistic is given by:

$$\mathcal{W} = \left(\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}_{\mathcal{H}_0}\right)^\mathsf{T} \mathcal{I} (\hat{\beta})\left(\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}_{\mathcal{H}_0} \right)$$

And my question is whether the respective cumulative logit intercepts should be included in the parameter vector for valid inference.

Comment: I don't understand the statement that the proportional odds assumption can be relaxed in robust variance estimation. I tend to see this assumption on par with say checking for potential non-linearities in regular linear regression, that is, this is not something you can dismiss easily.

Comment: We have differing ideas of the importance of these assumptions. I am only interested in inference. If you focus on the cumulative odds ratio as the parameter of interest in such a model, then robust variance estimates give you correct and consistent inference on that parameter regardless of the "assumptions" being met. The interpretation of the OR under non-proportionality is as a ordinally averaged cumulative odds ratio, a complicated weighted average of the ORs for each cumulant.

Comment: But that average no longer means anything because you have potentially missed the most important feature of the data. The proportional odds assumption _can_ be a useful simplification of reality, but if the deviations are too strong, then the model is essentially meaningless. Consider the textbook example where a scatterplot shows an U shaped relationship and you plot a linear relationship which shows no effect. Who cares about inference on the model with a linear relationship in that data?

Comment: Think about consistency and estimation: all proportional odds tests (like proportional hazards tests) will "reject" with large enough $n$. When I say that the assumption is violated, I mean that formal calibration tests are significant, but that the assumptions still "look right". I agree that egregious departures from this have strong implications, but it is so easy to visualize, it's virtually worthless to do anything other than inspect a graphic (like looking at a scatterplot for a linear regression model).

Comment: I make a distinction between the assumption and statitistical tests of that assumption. I continue to hold that the assumption is critical, but I agree that statistical tests of that assumption are pretty much meaningless. The assumption is never strictly true. When we choose a model we look at whether it is "true enough" to be useful, and a $p$-value is no measure of that. A statistical test can thus not tell us whether the model is useful or not (regardless of $n$).

Comment: Instead one should estimate a Generalized Ordered Logit, inspect the coefficients, and see if they are close enough. A statistical test can help you guard against over-interpretting "patterns" in the coefficients that could just as well have been the results of random noice introduced by sampling. So, a statistical test can only play a secondary role in model selection. The primary role just rests on the fingerspitzengefühl of the researcher.